# How to upgrade SPFX solution node version from node version 10 to version 14

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, spfx, sharepointframework

I have a SharePoint framework solution that builds using node version 10 however I want to upgrade the package node version **10 to 14** if I need to create a new same package or we have some command using that we can use or upgrade node 14.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/compatibility

delete node modules then update below in package json

```
@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.9,
gulp@4.0.2,
@microsoft/sp-build-web@1.13.0,
@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces@1.13.0,
@microsoft/sp-tslint-rules@1.13.0 --save
```

then

```
npm install
```

then update tsconfig

```
"extends": "./node_modules/@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.3/includes/tsconfig-web.json"
```

to

```
"extends": "./node_modules/@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.9/includes/tsconfig-web.json"
```

add below in gulp.js before build.initialize

```
var getTasks = build.rig.getTasks;
    
build.rig.getTasks = function () {
   var result = getTasks.call(build.rig);
   result.set('serve',result.get('serve-deprecated')); 
  return result;
};
```